# Multiple Levels of Children Entity Objects in Fluent NHibernate/NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a entity which has a list of Child1 objects. The mappings seem 
to work fine for this. If I try to add a list of Child2 objects to the 
Child1 entity and set up the mapping a xml mapping doesn't seem to get 
created and I get this error:

Test method 
vRATest.ORMTest.NHibernateTests.NHibernate_Should_Be_Able_To_Get_All_Routes­_Using_ProjectID 
threw exception:  NHibernate.MappingException: Association references 
unmapped class: vRA.Domain.RouteLocationNH.

I have checked my entities and mappings several times now but I can't 
seem to figure out how to make this 3rd level work. Is this even 
possible in Fluent NHibernate or even NHibernate? I am new to both of 
these technologies so thought I'd better ask. If anyone has a working 
example of 3 levels of entities that work I'd appreciate seeing how to 
do this.

thanks in advance! 
Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible.  The exception message indicates that you're missing a mapping for one of the classes in one of your `References<T>()` calls (or `many-to-one` in XML mappings) in one of your maps.

Go through your classes and make sure that you have a `ClassMap` class for every entity class that is referenced from any of your existing mappings.

The fact that the problem occurred after you setup the mapping from Child1 to Child2 indicates to me that it's a problem with Child2 or one of the classes that it references.